# Using self::STAT in relations to find the single latest related record

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am now having two tables `tbl_user` and `tbl_log`, and `User` and `Log` ActiveRecord classes respectively.

**tbl_log**

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `log_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

**User** class relations

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'rLog' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Log', 'user_id'),
    );
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to retrieve the latest record on `tbl_log`, that belongs to a certain user.

I have tried to add the following relation to the `User` class:

```
'lastLogDate' => array(self::STAT, 'Log', 'user_id', 'select'=>'log_date', 'order'=>'log_date DESC', 'group'=>'user_id', 'defaultValue'=>'N/A'),
```

so that I could retrieve the `log_date` from the latest record by calling something like:

```
$model = User::model()->findByPk($id);
echo $model->lastLogDate;
```

But then I realized it was actually not working properly. The `log_date` returned was always from the record with the smallest `id` on the `tbl_log` table, probably due to the behavior of **GROUP BY** and **ORDER BY** on a SQL query.

So now, I would like to know how (if possible) to achieve this by using a similar approach (i.e. using relations in the ActiveRecord class)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The idea to go is using 'order' and 'limit', example:

```
'order'=>'log_date DESC',
'limit'=>1,
```

But you were wrong when use this type of relationship `SELF::STAT`, it is used to count the returned of records, not latest record

I don't usually use it that way, instead here is how I will:

In `Log` model, you should have:

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'belongUser' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
    }
```

And it would be simple like below

```
//get first found Log record of the user by given user_id and sort by log_date DESCENDANT
    $lastLogDateRecord = Log::model()->with(array(
        'belongUser' => array(
            'condition' => 'user_id = :user_id',
            'params' => array('user_id'=>$id) //$id is user_id param what user want
        )
    ))->findByAttributes(array(), array('order' => 'log_date DESC'));
```